# Homestead not running on my local browser

Tags: php

I've tried setting up my Homestead by following the [steps](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#first-steps) outlined on the Laravel Homestead page.

I ran the vagrant up command to setup my Homestead in the VB. I also configured my Homestead.Yaml file according to the Laravel doc website. Yet the IP address on the Hosts file isn't taking me to the Laravel page.

This is what my Homestead.yaml looks like:
[Homestead.yaml with the necessary configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGHwa.png)

And Hosts looks like this:
[The hosts IP is same with that in the homestead.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWIXK.png)

What can be the problem that is preventing the Laravel page from running, and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please, post text instead of images.

Comment: Which error You get? Look at similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/28036879/205355